# Что лучше использовать в иерархии наследования super или модификатор protected, для доступа к родительским полям?

Tags: java

Допустим есть код :

```
public class Parent {

   private int parId;

   private String nameToSuper;
   protected String nameToProtected;

   public Parent () {
   }

   public String getNameToSuper() {
       return this.nameToSuper; 
   }

}


public class Sub extends Parent {

     public void example(String name) {
         String varSuperExample = super.getNameToSuper();
         String varProtectedExample = nameToProtected;
     }

}
```

Какой вариант использования, для доступа к переменной родительского из класса наследника, является предпочтительнее?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Боюсь, вы немного путаете понятия:

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушков, скорее всего, Вы правы. Я понимаю, что protected, является модификатором доступа и сужает область видимости. А super используется для доступа к членам родительского класса. Но все же, что лучше использовать если в классе наследнике нужно постоянно обращаться к полям класса предка?

Comment: для обращения к полям предка вам необязательно использовать super. Наследник их и так видит. вот если вам к примеру надо добраться до конструктора предка то надо super, или вы переопределили метод, но хотите обратиться к методу суперкласса (а имена то у них одинаковые)

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушков, если поле предка объявлено с модификатором private (чего требует инкапсуляция), то наследник может получить к нему доступ только используя getter для этого поля. Насколько я понимаю, то лаконичнее его вызвать используя super, а не просто имя метода. А вот если поле объявлено protected, то обращаться к полю можно по его имени.

Comment: а вы суперкласс и наследник в пределах одного класса создаёте?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушков, Нет.

Comment: В разных файлах сделайте и у родителя всё сделайте приватным и попробуйте обратиться из наследника к приватным полям и методам, хоть с супером, хоть без.

Comment: Константин Луговой, если не ошибаюсь, то предпочтительней обращаться через геттеры и сеттеры, которые надо сделать полям в классе предке

Comment: @YuriiS, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Public геттеры и сеттеры объявляются там же где и поля. А потомки их наследуют по умолчанию. А если вы сделаете в классе родителе  поле приватным, то потомок будет его видеть только через геттеры и сеттеры, которые унаследует. В классе потомке нельзя сделать геттеры и сеттеры для приватного поля суперкласса.